# How to get :focus & :valid value like form-control from bootstrap-select?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, label, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to add a float label on bootstrap selectpicker with only css. So in my code I want to float the label with `bootstrap-select:focus`. But the problem is this line doesn't work in the css. But if I use `bootstrap-select:active`, when holding mouse this seems to work.

I tried the floating label with normal selectbox applying `form-control` and in the normal selectbox everything works fine, but I want my selectbox to be more functional & good looking, so I am trying to use selectpicker. In `form-control` I used `:focus` & `:valid` to get the selectebox state and applied the floating label. [This is the example with `form-control`](https://jsfiddle.net/sinDbad/jc7qfL1e/)

This is the code with `.bootstrap-select:active` that works with mouse click.

```
.bootstrap-select:active + .form-control-placeholder {
    color: #da3338 !important;
    transform: translate(0, -1.2em);
    font-size: 70%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

[This is the example with `selectpicker`](https://jsfiddle.net/sinDbad/nv0deugh/)

The main point is that I want the label to float when the selectbox is focused, also when a valid option is selected from the drop down menu. I want to do this with pure css, but if I need js/jQuery I won't mind, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend looking into JavaScript or JQuery. If you made the :active class into a separate class for the label you could toggle between the two when the use clicks on the select. Check out [toggleClass in JQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp)

Comment: @CallumR After reading the toggleClass documentation I tried toggling between the classes, but as the name says it will toggle everytime I click (I don't know if I missed something). I actually want the label to float only when someone clicks once in the button & after that it will stay there floating until the focus gets away from the button or some valid value is set to the button. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: Ah okay, I hadn't thought about that. You could try an if statement before the toggle that checks to see if the select has a value? So `var selectValue =  $("#selectID").val()` and then `if (!selectValue) { this means that there is no value/the select is empty so do your toggle function}`

Comment: Hmm tried this way too, but I think the `$("#selectID").val()` isn't able to get a valid value as the float label is still toggling after the selectbox has a value present. I am not sure but I think bootstrap-selectpicker has a different way of getting value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after spending days in google I have come to a solution!

css classes:

```
.float {
    color: #da3338 !important;
    transform: translate(0, -1.1em);
    font-size: 75%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.changefloat {
    transform: translate(0, -1.1em);
    font-size: 75%;
}
```

jquery:

```
function float (){
    $(this).parents(".form-group").children("label").addClass("float");
}
function unfloat (){
    $(this).parents(".form-group").children("label").removeClass("float");
}
function changefloat (){
    $(this).parents(".form-group").children("label").addClass("changefloat");
}

$(".selectpicker").on("show.bs.select", float);
$(".selectpicker").on("hide.bs.select", unfloat);
$(".selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select", changefloat);
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/sinDbad/nv0deugh/74/)